# Ruby on Rails :Creating Migration Script for Authorization with Role Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

My Application as a User Model generate via Devise Gem. I want to associate with each user some roles via  many-to-many association through Assignment between User and Role. How do I generate migration script so that user is associated with some roles.Model classes will look like the following

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a migration like this:

```
rails g migration create_assignments_table
```

And fill that file with:

```
class CreateAssignmentsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :assignments do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :role

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I like to use `t.references` instead of `t.integer` to (just semantically) reflect the relations between the tables, but that's up to you.

Comment: i actually have only user model created for application that too doesn't contain any references to assignment table . . plus i also need to generate roles model with reference to assignment table how can i generate that ? It would be great if you could help

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. It seems you have the models created correctly, and you were just missing the JOIN table (assignments).

Comment: actually i dont have model created . . actually i am following this link https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model . They have given the generated models , but I want to learn how to generate models if user model has already been created and none other models have been created

Comment: You can just create the file under app/models and use the code you put in your example.

Comment: I would recommend you spending some time learning the basics of Rails migrations, and then come back with a more specific question. Either way, follow @agmcleod comment, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just need a create table migration.

```
 rails g migration create_assignments
```

And be sure it has the columns you need.

```
class CreateAssignments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :assignments do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :role_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: i actually have only user model created for application that too doesn't contain any references to assignment table . . plus i also need to generate roles model with reference to assignment table how can i generate that ? It would be great if you could help